# How to sum first 100 rows of a specific column using Awk?

Tags: awk

How to sum first 100 rows of a specific column using Awk? I wrote

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} NR<=100 {x+=$5}END {print x}' temp.txt
```

But this is taking lot of time to process; is there any other way which gives result quickly?

Comment: What do you mean with "lot of time to process"? How big is your input? What do you see if you prepend `time` to the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Just `exit` after the required first 100 records:

```
awk -v iwant=100 '{x+=$5} NR==iwant{exit} END{print x+0}' test.in
```

Take it out for a spin:

```
$ for i in {1..1000}; do echo 1 >> test.in ; done # thousand of records
$ awk -v iwant=100 '{x+=$1} NR==iwant{exit} END{print x+0}' test.in
100
'{x+=$5} NR==iwant{exit} END{print x+0}'
```

Comment: That's an evil reputation

Comment: I GOT IT. Hopefully it won't stick.

Comment: `'NR<=iwant {x+=$5} NR==iwant {print x; exit}'` duplicates the condition (duplicated code is always undesirable) and would fail to produce any output if there were fewer than `iwant` lines in the input file. You should use `'{x+=$5} NR==iwant{exit} END{print x+0}'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can always trim the input and use the same script

```
head -100 file | awk ... your script here ...
```